# printing out letter every min Python

Tags: python, printing, repeat

so i am trying to figure this out for school. Im trying to print x out every minute and every ten min it will print on a new line. so far i cant get the "printing x" every min down. can someone please help.
this is my code

```
import time;
inTime = float(input("type in how many second"))
oldTime = time.time()-inTime


print (time.time())

def tenMin(oldTime):
    newTime = time.time()
    if ((newTime - oldTime)>= 25):
        return True
    else:
        False

while (True):
        if (tenMin==True):
            print ("x")
            newTime = time.time()
            oldtime = time.time()
else:
    oldTime = time.time()
    continue
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the number of Min And Ten Min from an input or you just want a software to print after 1 min something and after 10 min something else?

Comment: i want it to print x out every min on a single line than after ten min, the cycle starts over again

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. if you use the 
    "end=''
it would print in one line
and my program was wrong on the else line and all i need to do is delete some unwanted text. but i would like to thank everyone with helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is in the line

```
if (tenMin==True):
```

You compare a function reference to a boolean, clearly the answer would be False. You have to pass a parameter

```
if (tenMIn(oldTime)):
```

...

Comment: thanks but it seems to only print out once and it doesnt seem like its counting til 60 to print out another one

Answer (score 0):

First you have some issues with you code:

1. `else:
       False` - This is not true syntax in python.
2. If you want timer, why are you asking the user for input?
3. You have a logic problem:

   `inTime = float(input("type in how many second"))`

   `oldTime = time.time()-inTime`

   time.time is float yes, but can a user really know what to print in UnixTime?

I'll suggest a simple solution **it's not the very best** but it works.
It will print "x" every 1 Min and after 10 Min it will print "\n" (new line)

```
import time

def main():

    #both timers are at the same start point
    startTimerTen = time.time()
    startTimerMin = startTimerTen

    while True:
        getCurrentTime = time.time()
        if getCurrentTime - startTimerTen >= 600:
            # restart both parameters
            startTimerTen = getCurrentTime
            startTimerMin = getCurrentTime
            print "This in 10 min!\n"
        if getCurrentTime - startTimerMin >= 60:
            # restart only min parameter
            startTimerMin = getCurrentTime
            print "x"


   #end of main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: could we use a for loop instead of the while loop?

Comment: You can, but you need some condition, do you have any?